# Set l10n_mode of field based on condition (CType / Layout / PageTree)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Is it possible to change the l10n_mode of a field (e.g. assets) based on the CType, layout or PageTree?

Use case:

- Default l10n_mode of assets is 'exclude' (set by a site package extension)
- For a specific CType it's necessary to change the assets field in translations (to allow translation of captions)

In TYPO3 7.6 the following was possible:

```
[PIDinRootline = 173]
     config.sys_language_softMergeIfNotBlank = tt_content:assets
[end]
```

**EDIT**

```
sys_language_softMergeIfNotBlank
```

was removed in TYPO3 8.7, so this is not possible anymore. [Breaking Change](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Breaking-79243-RemoveL10n_modeMergeIfNotBlank.html)

Answer (score 0):

In `TYPO3 8.7` you can use below typoscript condition.

For Page Layout.

```
[page|layout = 1]
     config.sys_language_softMergeIfNotBlank = tt_content:assets
[end]
```

For pageTree.

```
[treeLevel = levelnumber, levelnumber, ...]
    config.sys_language_softMergeIfNotBlank = tt_content:assets
[end]
```

For Ctype

```
[page|field = value]
    config.sys_language_softMergeIfNotBlank = tt_content:assets
[end]
```

For more typoscript condition [Click Here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html)

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work anymore, because mergeIfNotBlank was removed in TYPO3 8.7:
[Breaking Change 1](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Breaking-79243-RemoveL10n_modeMergeIfNotBlank.html) and [Breaking Change 2](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Breaking-79243-RemoveSys_language_softMergeIfNotBlank.html)